# Most appropriate layout for (Computer) Network Diagram

Tags: javascript, html, networking, d3.js, diagram

I'm trying to develop a HTML/JS based "(computer) network diagram". By this I mean boxes linking to other boxes, and more importantly, boxes contained *inside* the bounds of other boxes.

### Simplified Use Case - to explain the layout requirements

The use case is VPC (huge box) with AZ inside (2 or 3 big boxes stacked next to each other), and subnets inside each of those (boxes stacked on top of each other), and EC2s inside that (lots of small boxes next to each other).

[image: Network Diagram]

While I've tried a number of methods (see below) I haven't found a suitable layout for my diagram and am wondering if my needs are so unique that I need to roll my own.

## What I want help with...

- I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious in my research (in terms of options for a HTML5/JS solution)
- Am I taking the right approach looking for a framework or are these requirements too special?
- Should I consider writing my own layout (or does someone have a good idea for a good layout to start with)
- Is there a framework that does visual grouping well (e.g draw a big box that contains smaller boxes, maybe a few levels deep)

### My Research:

1. Webcola (can use with d3) http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/
2. D3 http://d3js.org/
3. JointJS http://www.jointjs.com/demos/devs

#### Webcola

I originally tried Webcola as the following example seemed the most promising:
http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/smallgroups.html

I found the documentation to be lacking, a few of the links are dead, and when trying to combine the "Layout with hierarchical grouping" with "Alignment constraints with guidelines" the page failed to load.

#### D3.js

This appears to have lots of documentation, although I couldn't find a single example that came close to what I wanted to build.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout

Pack Layout seems the closest, with nesting used to represent the hierarchy.
The problem with this method is the size of each node is not uniform (I can just set them all to 1) and the example uses circles (this appears to be a hard rule with this layout, I think).

#### JointJS

http://www.jointjs.com/demos/devs

This appears to have a nice example with what appears to be a group and inputs/outputs (although the node can escape the bounds of its parent which isn't ideal.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Would [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) suit you?  There were a couple of conversations on gg about this, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/72cl6POpVlQ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/EK5KiNXtng0).  If you follow the discussions in those posts you'll see some chat about [Dagre](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre) which is pitched as a javascript replacement for Graphviz.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @JimGarrison I didn't want to position this as a recommendation for a tool (although I did include my own research). I'm more asking about what sort of layout I should consider using. Do you think my question is completely off topic? I want to clarify I'm not after "use this tool, it's the best", but more "you should consider an x style layout".

Comment: Regarding d3.js, I'd go for a tree or cluster diagram.
If you really want something like the bubbles, check out the treemap

Comment: neither of those seem to allow me to easily put one node into another node. i don't like bubbles, i want boxes!

Comment: so... how do you actually want to use this, I'm not following the end goal here. Is this a tool that you'll click somewhere and a box appears, or is there a separate form that you use that will add things to the diagram?

Comment: You supply an AWS account that has read-only access, and this tool gets all that data and draws a network diagram for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I did undersand your problem well, it can be done with HTML/CSS only :

- the VPC div (container) is in position relative the and float left
- position relative too inside an again float left with clear left if
- you want to create another line

Beware of the width of the div

Comment: The example I gave is very much simplified (just showing you the general layout I need to end up with). I will need to handle linking between nodes (multiple links), parent/child relationships, potentially move nodes around the screen, animate them, and read data in from a source...the sort of stuff you get with a diagram framework with a purpose/custom built layout. Rolling my own is a potential solution, but only one I want to resort to once I'm sure there isn't anything that could help with the scaffolding.

Comment: Did you have a look at Darge? It seems to have most of the things you're after (including the box's!).

Comment: I think I came across that (can't remember/find the link to review that though), can't remember why it didn't make my shortlist. Does it have an example of a box within a box?

Comment: Some examples [here](http://cs.brown.edu/people/jcmace/d3/graph.html?id=small.json), [here](http://www.daviddurman.com/automatic-graph-layout-with-jointjs-and-dagre.html) and [here](http://nlpviz.bpodgursky.com/home)

Comment: none of these layouts come close to the layout I require